# Why does the Torah explicitly endorse the use of lead, a carcinogenic metal, in regards to Tevilah?

Tags: health-safety-shmira, tevilas-keilim-dipping, metals

In Parshas מטות, the Torah describes 6 different metals which require Tevilah ([Bamidbar 31:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.31.22)), one of them being lead. (Gold, silver, copper, iron, tin, & lead.)

It is learned out that all metals require Tevilah [1]. (Even aluminum depending on if its viewed as a 'vessel' or merely disposable.)

Why does the Torah enumerate lead as one of the 6 prototypical metals that require Tevilah? Granted at that point in time, many cultures used lead for vessels, albeit, lead could've at least been implicitly included just as Titanium, 304 Stainless Steel, or Tungsten is. Why explicitly mention a carcinogenic material that's hazardous to human health?

The Torah places great emphasis on וְנִשְׁמַרְתֶּ֥ם מְאֹ֖ד לְנַפְשֹׁתֵיכֶ֑ם, to take great care of one's body ([Devarim 4:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.4.15)), and many commentators find rational in numerous Mitzvohs providing protection against many types of diseases, for example:

- Ringworm from pork
- AIDS from homosexuality
- Netilat Yadayim, which most probably has protected Jews from the Bubonic plague
- Halachos of being clean from fecal matter ([Devarim 23:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.23.14))
- Quick burial of the dead, which also prevents more diseases from a dead body
- Kashrus (draining blood, salting meat, etc.)
- and too many more to list here.

I know that the primary goal of the Torah isn't meant to be a health-book or medical journal. But at the very least, why did it endorse Toveling the carcinogenic metal known as lead/עֹפָֽרֶת?

```
[1]: Mesechtas Avoda Zara 5:36, Tur Y.D. 120, Shulchan Aruch Y.D. 120:1, Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 37:1, Mishnah Berurah O.C. 323:31, Aruch Ha’shulchan Y.D.120:23
```

Comment: It is not clear cut that all metals require tevillah (mideoraita) - it is possible that this list of six is exhaustive

Comment: The Gemara includes Glass even though it isn't a metal, albeit DeRabanan. And nowadays, don't we anyways Tovel Titanium with a Bracha?

Comment: Not everyone would say a bracha on titanium. See [here](http://rabbikaganoff.com/tag/when-to-toyvel-keilim/), under the section "Other Metals"

Comment: I recall learning that the Torah doesn't endorse slavery, but it puts rules in place to accommodate the human practice of having slaves.

Comment: The examples you gave are not commanded to us to protect our health rather they are gezaras hakasuv. Just bc they may or may not have health benefits that happen at the same time as fulfilling them is not the same thing as saying we were commanded to do such and such for the explicit purpose of protecting ones health. It's also not a mitzvah to make use of lead only that it need be toiveled if it is used

Comment: @JoelK Thank you for the link!

According to one school of thought (Tiferes Yisrael), why did the Torah list lead? It could've been included with other metals. Or namely, why mention any metals at all? Just say all metals require Tevilah. What was the point of enumerating? Was it to show common examples in those days?
According to the other school of thought (Igros Moshe via a letter from Rav Yaakov Kamenetski), why indeed does lead require Tevilah? Is there any logical reason, or must we say it is a Chok?

Answer (score 2):

It did strike me as a little odd, too.

There's no mitzvah saying "hey, go use lead." Presumably these six were the ones commonly seen at the time.

And while certain mitzvos may help with health (you didn't mention *circumcision* and HIV transmission), there's also a point at which God left stuff for humans to figure out on their own.

The Gemara says that after Day Seven of creation, God "put an idea into Adam's head", *hey what if I strike rocks together? Oh cool, fire!* The point is that scientific and technological development would be a course for us to chart.

Answer (score 2):

The Birchas Asher on that passuk is bothered that it can’t be what we refer to today as lead, since that melts in fire.

> ואת העֹפרת. אונקלוס מתרגם: וית אברא. ואף על פי כן קשה קצת לקבל שזהו העופרת שבלשוננו, שהרי זו נמסה מהר למדי, כלומר אינה באה באש

Additionally, the Sforno, mentions a reason why it picked these 6 items instead of any other metal

> אך את הזהב אבל כלי מתכות מלבד אותה טהרה צריך שתגעילו אותם

> however, metal objects require an additional procedure before they are ritually clean, namely immersion in a ritual bath, (or rinsing in boiling water, or even making it red-hot, depending on how these utensils had been used.) (Sefaria)הזהב